# manipulate returned fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to manipulate (for example concatenate) returned fields from a query?

This is how I created my index:

```
PUT /megacorp/employee/1
{
    "first_name" : "John",
    "last_name" :  "Smith",
    "age" :        25,
    "about" :      "I love to go rock climbing",
    "interests": [ "sports", "music" ]
}
```

And this is how I query it:

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}}
}
```

The response is this:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "megacorp",
        "_type": "employee",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Smith",
          "age": 25,
          "about": "I love to go rock climbing",
          "interests": [
            "sports",
            "music"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

That's all working fine.

What I want is to concatenate two fields from the _source and display it in the output as a new field.

first_name and last_name should be combined to a new field "full_name". I can't figure out how to do that without creating a new field in my index. I have looked at "copy_to", but it requires you to explicitly set the store property in the mapping and you have to explicitly ask for the stored field in the query. But the main downside is that when you do both that, the first_name and last_name are returned comma separated. I would like a nice string: "John Smith"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
  "query": {"match_all": {}},
  "script_fields": {
    "combined": {
      "script": "_source['first_name'] + ' ' + _source['last_name']"
    }
  }
}
```

And  you need to enable [dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`script_fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) to achieve that

```
GET /megacorp/employee/_search
{
    "query": {"match_all": {}},
    "script_fields" : {
        "full_name" : {
            "script" : "[doc['first_name'].value, doc['last_name'].value].join(' ')"
        }
    }
}
```

You need to make sure to [enable dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting) in order for this to work.